# Audio Unit Instrument adding master effects

Tags: xcode5, audiounit

Like in a VST instrument there is a processReplacing (Render) function where the sum of every MIDI note will be played at the same time, and you can add master effects to all the mixed notes.

But in Audio Unit creating an instrument there is only the Render function in every SynthNote through the SyntNote class, how can I apply master effects to the summed buffer stream out?

I can't find any function to inherit so that I have some place after the synth note Render to apply my effect algorithms before it is sent to the sound device.

Someone who knows a function somewhere in the SDK?
I'm using Core Audio Utility classes (SDK) version 1.0.4
Inheriting AUMonotimbralInstrumentBase and SynthNote.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that you shouldn't inherit from the AUInstrumentBase class where the Render function is. The Sample code from Apple is kind of confusing, and I hope this will help someone else too.